# RDP from MAC OS X to Windows Server 2008 R2 License Error

Tags: windows, macos, rdp

ERROR

"You were disconnected from the Windows-based computer because of problems during the licensing protocol"

I have scoured the Internet and have read it can be fixed...but no one has given me a working fix. I have tried many fixes but still no luck =(.

Anyone know a FUNCTIONING fix for 10.7 and or 10.8

I am using http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client (the latest version) to connect to Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. Running RDS with a 5 User CAL. No Active Directory just basic accounts as the local IT team hasn't a clue how to use AD and I am a thousand miles away.

Comment: Can you use Remote Desktop from a Windows client to the server in question?  Have you tried an alternative client such as FreeRDP?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try Thinomenon RDC for Mac? It properly supports redirect token, which could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found these 2 links which seems to have fixed the issue (Hope it's not the same you tried !!!), esp follow vezard & Martijn Huizer's response:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/8e28b0af-b374-4ca0-a255-5fd854bdc7fa

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2477133

Hope it solves your issue !

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has released a new RDP client in the app store.  So far It seems to work.

Comment: I updated the software and it still gave me the same error.  Then I found the CoRD solution (mentioned below)

Answer (score 0):

I try to be careful where I download from, and I found this Remote Desktop client option on sourceforge.net - a download site I am familiar with and trust:

http://cord.sourceforge.net

From their site:

> CoRD is a Mac OS X remote desktop client for Microsoft Windows computers using the RDP protocol. It's easy to use, fast, and free for anyone to use or modify.

I am using Max OS X 10.7